# Is there a way to call a method of a class instance in one line?

Tags: php, instance

I work with a tiny framework, its main object is available for its childs (controllers, models, views) via

```
mainobject::instance()
```

Wiki of the framework recommends to add in desired controller method

```
$mainobject = mainobject::instance()
```

So it’s become available for models through the single variable. I am in doubt if this is really handy, to define that variable in every single model’s method to get for example global config variable.

```
class MyAnotherModel extends FrameworksModel 
{
    …
    my_method() {
        global $mainobject;
        …
        if ($mainobject->config['something_here'];
        $mainobject->controller->othermodel->othermodelsarray['somestring']; 
    }
}
```

Anyway this is a huge string and I’d rather prefer to make it a bit larger calling an instance then to write two strings each time. I mean, write

```
mainobject::instance->config['goods']
mainobject::instance->controller->othermodel->othermodelsmethodgiveme('power');
```

But I don’t know if it is possible to implement, since controller class does not provide calling an instance as a variable. I suppose it may be possible via getter method… if there was such method. So what can I do without rewriting original mainobject class?

inb4 long strings are inconveniently to type — there is no problem since I can use abbrevs in emacs and make typing phrase short.

Comment: `mainobject::instance()->config['goods']` should work

Comment: Can’t imagine that it would work but it does. Thanks.

Comment: Why would it not work?  Break it down into pieces.  You're calling the static method and getting the return value which you are then operating on.  The issue with your original code is that you weren't calling the method but instead trying to access it as though it were an attribute.

Comment: It just looks like methods can have properties. I know it’s cool when whatever you call, a property or a method, is by default an object but never seen that in php. Actually it is not, just looks similar to.

Comment: In almost all major languages the addition of the `()` indicates that the method is being called and you're now operating on the return value.  Without the `()` it would be a reference to the method itself and _that_ would indicate that the method would have properties.  Making that distinction can spare a lot of confusion down the road.

Comment: Matt, maybe post it as an answer so it can get closed?